# Getting img's src path and convert it to json

Tags: jquery, json

I'm getting some html content via ajax and on the callback I'd like to get all src paths and convert them into a json. I'm always  getting 404 errors, because it loads the images. How can i prepend it from loading? Also, I'm getting the error: Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QgFMe/

The only thing i can think of is regex, but i would prefer a non regex solution.

Thanks

Comment: I've seen this come up before (but can't find the question) - it seemed that in this case regex was the only viable answer - jQuery does attempt to load the images if you use it to parse the HTML, as you've found.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var pics = [];
    $(this).find("img").each(function () {
        pics.push($(this).attr("src"));                                                                                                                                           
    });

    console.log(pics);

    var json_data = JSON.stringify(pics);

    console.log(json_data);
});
```

Comment: If you are using `map` you can just do it like this: `var pics = $(this).find("img").map(function() { return this.src; });`

Comment: if you're going to accumulate yourself you should use `.each()` instead of `.map()`, but the right answer is to use `.map(...).get()` instead.

Comment: @AndreasAL you still need `.get()` too

Comment: hmm, i was sure i tried each and somehow it didn't work. That's why i looked up map. Hmm, but seems at this time, there was some other error. Anyway thanks, I'm going to try it out and reply!

Comment: @xotix .map() _iterates over an array_ using a _callback_ and _returns_ another jQuery object, but one whose elements are not necessarily DOM elements.  `.each()` also iterates using a callback, but then returns the original jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your JSON error, pass the output of `.map()` to `.get()`.

This converts the pseudo jQuery object returned by `.map()` into a real array:

```
var pics = $(this).find("img").map(function () {
    return this.src;                                                                                                                                          
}).get();
```

NB: `$(this).attr('src') === this.src`

I don't know a solution to your 404 error though - see comments above.